# Novel with plot element of a water world with multi-armed creatures which communicate by joining arms

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

This novel had a female protagonist as I recall.

A spacecraft was travelling with some purpose, dropped out of hyperspace mid-journey to find a planet with undersea cities and aliens something line sea-stars, with multiple arms, communicated with each other by joining arms, formed a network that way.

I recall that later in the narrative this planet was destroyed.

Comment: Relevant meta discussion; [Is this question correctly closed as a duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12314/is-this-question-correctly-closed-as-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Gw'oth appear in "Fleet of Worlds", the *Ringworld* novels by Larry Niven and Edward M. Lerner, and in three of the sequels.

Lerner has [an article about the species](http://blog.edwardmlerner.com/2013/04/quoth-gwoth.html) on his blog.

> A Gw’o loosely resembles a starfish crossed with an octopus. The
>   Gw’o’s five flexible extremities are equally spaced around a disklike
>   central mass.  Each tubular tentacle—tubacle—harkens back to the Gwo’s
>   ancestral, free-ranging tube worms. From the mouth inward, arrayed in
>   consecutive rings around the tube’s inner surface, are teeth, eyes,
>   ears, and the myriad chemoreceptors for taste and smell. Shared
>   organs, including most of the central nervous system, reside in the
>   central disk. Flattened and with its tubacles outstretched, a Gw’o
>   spans about two-thirds of a meter.

Comment: Yes that's it, it was "Fleet of Worlds".  Thanks.